# new Object isn't actually new?

Tags: java, networking, tcp

I'm having some problem using an ArrayList in java, I'm creating a new class object, giving that values, adding that object to the arrayList and then using the keyword "new" to the object already used, re-using it with different data, but the data that isn't changed, but was set before, is still set?

Here is my code

```
private static ArrayList<PongServerThread> games = new ArrayList<PongServerThread>();
private static int players = 0;
private static PongServerThread game;

public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{   
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Start of Loop");

        if(game.getPlayers() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for players");
        }
        if(game.getPlayers() == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Game Added");
            games.add(game);
            games.get((games.size())-1).start();
            game.setPlayers(0);
        }

        game = new PongServerThread();
    }
}
```

this code works fine, but in my PongServerThread, once two clients have connected, main will start the thread, and a new PongServerThread object needs to be started, so 2 more clients can connect to that thread, but what is happening is, once 2 clients the thread starts, the new thread here

```
game = new PongServerThread();
```

this will be created again, but when a new client connects, it will take over the first client, and if another client connects, it will take over the 2nd client, and so on and so forth, so what is happening is the line for

```
game = new PongServerThread();
```

Isn't really making a new PongServerThread, How would I go about fixing this? also here is the console output when 2 clients have connected, then 1 more connects

```
Start of Loop
Waiting for players
Pong
400.0:301.0:60.0:300.0:740.0:300.0
Server started
Server was setup and will try to create a socket
Client Connected with ID:0
Checking readLine value
Client Connected with ID:1
Start of Loop
Game Added
Pong
400.0:300.0:60.0:300.0:740.0:300.0
Server started
Server was setup and will try to create a socket
Checking readLine value
Client Connected with ID:0
Checking readLine value
```

Update for Ryan -----

Here is my server constructor

```
public PongServerThread() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

    //Setup
            super("PongServerThread");
            setupPong();
            boolean listen = false;
            boolean playing = false;
            System.out.println(rtnInfo());


            System.out.println("Server started");
            //Create a serverSocket to listen on
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                listen = true;
                System.out.println("Server was setup and will try to create a socket");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Could not listen on port:" + port);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            while(listen)
            {
                /*PongPlayerThread player1 = */
                players[idPlayer] = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), idPlayer, rtnInfo());
                players[idPlayer].start();
                System.out.println("Client Connected with ID:" + idPlayer);
                players[0].passData(rtnInfo());
                idPlayer++;     
                if(idPlayer > 1)
                {
                    listen = false;
                    playing = true;
                }
            }

            int timer = 0;
            System.out.println("Server Closed");
            serverSocket.close();

}
```

---Update---

I just noticed that I was declaring the some of the variables static, and this is most probably the reason why I was getting the error, but now when i try to run my server code

```
class Main
{
// Variable
private ArrayList<PongServerThread> games = new ArrayList<PongServerThread>();
private int players = 0;
private PongServerThread game;

public void main( String args[] ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{   
    //PongServerThread game = new PongServerThread();
    /*if(pt.getPlayers() == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Started");
        pt.start();
    }*/

     PongServerThread game = new PongServerThread();
        while(true)
        {
            games.add(game);
            System.out.println("Game Added");
            game.start();

            game = new PongServerThread();
        }
    /*System.out.println("Pong");
    PongModel model = new PongModel();
    PongView  view  = new PongView();
                      new PongController( model, view );

    model.addObserver( view );       // Add observer to the model

    view.setVisible(true);           // Display Screen
    model.makeActiveObject();        // Start play*/
}
}
```

I get this error

```
Could not get Input/Output from server
```

Would anyone know why I would be getting that? I can paste more code if needed.

Comment: So... what does PongServerThread's constructor look like?

Comment: sets up the everything for the pong game, so sets up a socket, and will listen for clients until two have connected, when they have connected listen is then equal to false

Comment: I can't make any sense out of 'using the keyword "new" to the object already used'. Please translate.

Comment: Ok, after 2 clients connect, I need to create a whole new instance of PongServerThread, so using the keyword new it would reset my variable, all I'm trying to do is once 2 clients connect to a PongServerThread, that variable is stored into an array for later use, and a new PongServerThread variable is ready and waiting for 2 new clients

Comment: It looks like `game = new ...` should go in the second if statement. As it is right now, you're creating a new game no matter how many players you currently have.

Comment: This is true, but still, a "new game" is never being created. as I stated above, when two clients have joined a new game should be created, so when a new client connects they connect to the new game, but what is happened is the the new client (3rd client) will take over the 1st client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because PongServerThread() returns only when there is a game with 2 players, you can simplify you main function quite much:

```
{
    PongServerThread game = new PongServerThread();
    while(true)
    {
        games.add(game);
        System.out.println("Game Added");
        game.start();

        game = new PongServerThread();
    }
}
```

Line `game.setPlayers(0);` was quite strange: why to set player count of the game to zero, when the game is just started with two players.

EDIT:

If I understand correctly, the `setPlaysers(0)` call sets zero to static variable `players`. That is the reason why 3rd client will get ID = 0; and 4th client got ID = 1;
Maybe that make it look like 'overwriting'.

So removing `game.setPlayers(0);` will fix this, and all players will get unique identifier.

Comment: this is correct, but I want a new game to be created, when two users connect, once two users have connected, it creates a new server, but when a new client tries to connect, nothing happens. which means the pongServer is at 2 players, and won't listen for any more, I'm just trying to create a new instance of PongServerThread and not over writing the pre-existing one.

Comment: @Canvas : I don't see any overwriting in the code. The line `game = new PongServerThread();` won't overwite the existing game object.

Comment: How would I go about doing that then? what I'm trying to get to happen  is, a new pongServerThread is created, it will wait for two clients to connect, once two clients are connected, that pongServerThread will start, and a new pongServerThread will be created, which will then wait for another two clients to connect to, and then so on and so forth.

Comment: Yes, that is clear. I think that the code I provided will do excatly that:  When the existing PongServerThread object in main() function have 2 players, it will start the existing PongServerThread object, and it will create a new PongServerThread object.

Comment: Ok I just tried your code and i get this error ---Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Pong.PongServerThread.<init>(PongServerThread.java:152)
 at Pong.Main.main(Main.java:34)---
line 152 is this ---players[idPlayer] = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), idPlayer, rtnInfo());--- and line 32 is this ---game = new PongServerThread();---

Answer (score 1):

In order to start a thread, you must call, e.g.:

```
game.start();
```

In general, it is preferable to implement `Runnable`, then say:

```
Runnable myThread = ...;
new Thread(myThread).start();
```

Comment: He may be calling it in the constructor. We don't know. I suspect this is likely the case, because he doesn't do any reading/writing in the main thread.

Comment: True, I hadn't thought of that, thanks!  Upvoted your comment. :)

Comment: the games.get((games.size())-1).start(); line starts the thread, This does work as my pong game updates fine.